# How to fetch username and password fields from external txt or excel file in selenium by python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How to fetch username and password fields in facebook from external text excel file in selenium by python?

```
username = 'How To Fectch From External Txt File?'
passowrd = 'How To Fectch From External Txt File?'

emailInput = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
passwordInput = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
loginButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form/table/tbody/tr/td/label/input")

ActionChains(driver) \
    .move_to_element(emailInput) \
    .click() \
    .send_keys(username) \
    .perform()

ActionChains(driver) \
    .move_to_element(passwordInput) \
    .click() \
    .send_keys(passowrd) \
    .perform()

ActionChains(driver) \
    .move_to_element(loginButton) \
    .click() \
    .perform()
```

Comment: Selenium is not able to interact with excel files. Check this link in order to interact with excel of something else. Once you have the data you want you can pass them to selenium functions: https://chercher.tech/python/excel-selenium-python

Answer (score 0):

Selenium by itself doesnt provide any api to read or write files.

These operations should be done using python code(or any programming language you have to opted to script).

Here is a link which explains file operations using python
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/file-operation

Additionally i would suggest to store your data in a JSON/CSV/XLSX